# Linux mint black screen after installing extension

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

I have been running my linux without problems up until now and when I tried to install specific extension, everything but my mouse cursor was frozen. Restarting my PC didn't do any good - black screen and system unable to start its desktop environment.

Running `startx` does nothing - black screen with my cursor only visible.

Running `sudo cinnamon --replace` gives me the following output:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Window manager error: Unable to open X display
```

I ran the following command:

```
egrep -i 'error|fail' ~/.xsession-errors
```

which gave me the following output:

```
** (nm-applet:2907): CRITICAL **: nm_secret_agent_register: assertion 'priv->registered == FALSE' failed
[WARN 18:56:42.705382] [relevancy-backend-zg:63] Unable to check Zeitgeist data sources: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine was not provided by any .service files
[WARN 18:56:42.708795] [relevancy-backend-zg:123] GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine was not provided by any .service files
[WARN 18:56:42.708885] [relevancy-backend-zg:209] GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine was not provided by any .service files
```

Along with this line which is repeated at least 30 times

```
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_screen_get_monitor_geometry: assertion 'monitor >= 0 && monitor < screen->n_monitor_infos' failed
```

ending with this:

```
(cinnamon:2893): Cjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: InternalError: too much recursion
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_screen_get_monitor_geometry: assertion 'monitor >= 0 && monitor < screen->n_monitor_infos' failed
(cinnamon:2893): Cjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: (null)
(cinnamon:2893): Cjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: (null)
(cinnamon:2893): Cjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: (null)
```

Or to put everything as one:

```
** (nm-applet:2907): CRITICAL **: nm_secret_agent_register: assertion 'priv->registered == FALSE' failed
[WARN 18:56:42.705382] [relevancy-backend-zg:63] Unable to check Zeitgeist data sources: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine was not provided by any .service files
[WARN 18:56:42.708795] [relevancy-backend-zg:123] GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine was not provided by any .service files
[WARN 18:56:42.708885] [relevancy-backend-zg:209] GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine was not provided by any .service files
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_screen_get_monitor_geometry: assertion 'monitor >= 0 && monitor < screen->n_monitor_infos' failed
(cinnamon:2893): Cjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: InternalError: too much recursion
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_screen_get_monitor_geometry: assertion 'monitor >= 0 && monitor < screen->n_monitor_infos' failed
(cinnamon:2893): Cjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: (null)
```

Purging and installing `cinnamon` again lead to no result as well.

- The extension I tried to install is [Panel span](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/20)
- I am using `Linux Mint` with `Cinnamon`
- `Cinnamon` version is `2.6.13`
- My `Mint` version is `17.2 - Rafaela`

Any kind of help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! If you have solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer (yes, you may post an answer to your own question) rather than editing it into your question. Thank you